# Como obtener la última redirección desde una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño módulo de redirecciones para un pequeño sistema online. Tengo una tabla donde almaceno las redirecciones:

```
id  | origen     | destino
----------------------------------
1   | //a.com    | //b.com
----------------------------------
2   | //b.com    | //c.com
----------------------------------
3   | //c.com    | //d.com
```

y así sucesivamente como hago a través de una consulta mysql que al buscar origen = '//a.com' obtener '//d.com'?

Evitando así hacer 2 redirecciones innecesarias, pasando por b.com y c.com. La cantidad de pasos intermedios pueden ser ninguno o más de 2, el anterior es solo un ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Necesariamente debe ser por query? Sinceramente, este tipo de cosas son más sencillas de manejar a nivel de aplicación que de base de datos.

Comment: Creo que debe haber alguna forma de lograrlo con una única consulta sql. Actualmente lo logro pero haciendo una consulta para cada resultado, y antes una redirección por cada registro, lo cual era muy poco eficiente.

Comment: Una solución creo que podria ser crear una función mysql (no un procedimiento) y usarlo recursivamente o con un bucle en un procedimiento que pare cuando ya no se encuentren resultados sustituyendo una variable que sera el ultimo destino encontrado.
No se si me explico bien. Lo malo es que obligatoriamente  tendrias que ir recorriendo las filas que tengan relación. Buscas un destino a traves del origen y luego otro destino a partir del ultimo destino obtenido como origen.

Comment: Puede que creando dos tablas separadas origen y destino y relacionarlas a traves de una tercera tabla que tenga claves foraneas de las otras 2 sea más facil.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres encontrar la fila con el ID más alto, puedes hacer:

```
SELECT destino FROM tabla WHERE origen='//a.com' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```